# How to sync between two dates in month for both Excel and Oracle?

Tags: excel, oracle

I tried to calculating between two dates in months for both excel and oracle.But some of cases failed

excelsheet :-

> =(YEAR(B2)-YEAR(A2))*12+MONTH(B2)-MONTH(A2)

oracle :-

> round(months_between(to_date(date1),date2),1)

what is best way to sync for both  excel and oracle

Comment: "But some cases failed" is not very helpful, can you explain more what the issue is?

Comment: Might try [`DATEDIF`](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/DATEDIF-function-bd549d1c-f829-4691-a77d-4a1e3d42bc1a).  You really need to more clearly state what the expected output should be for a range of inputs (e.g. how to handle the fringe cases).